# orienting a point in polar coordinates along a particular unit vector

Tags: vectors, circles, polar-coordinates, parametric

I have the center of a circle $\vec{c}$ in 3 space and the radius $r$. I also have a unit vector $\hat{v}$ defining the orientation of the plane of the circle.

I wish to parameterize this circle and place a single point on the circle.

My logic is, imagine I have a point in polar coordinates.

I could describe it as

$$\vec{p} = r \cos(\lambda) \hat{i}+ r \sin(\lambda)\hat{j}+0\hat{k}$$

Now the way I'm imagining this is that this point can sweep out the entire circle just by modifying $\lambda$.

Intuitively, I can move this point so that the center of the circle it sweeps out lays at the point of the circle I want.

Thus, I can do

$$\vec{p} = \vec{c} + r \cos(\lambda) \hat{i}+ r \sin(\lambda)\hat{j}+0\hat{k}$$

However this still doesn't give me the right orientation. I wish the plane of the circle to be perpendicular to $\hat{v}$. I am stuck with my initial orientation of my circle and now I wish to reorient the circle along the unit vector $\hat{v}$.

How do I do this?

Comment: The vector v is normal to the plane of the circle right?

Comment: Yes exactly, I will clarify that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Method 1**: *2 parameters, and you'd get a disc instead of a circle*

Take all vectors on the unit ball with center at origin. Take their cross product with $\hat{v}$ (this will leave behind only that part of each vector which is perpendicular to $\hat{v}$. Finally multiply by $r$ and add $\vec{c}$
$$r(\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)\hat{i}+\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)\hat{j}+\sin(\theta)\hat{j})\times\hat{v}+\vec{c}$$

**Method 2**: *1 parameter, and you'd get a circle. But need to choose something first...*

Choose any plane (passing through origin) of which $\hat{v}$ is not a part of. Since $\hat{v}$ can't simultaneously be on the XY, YZ and ZX planes, so we assume (WLOG) that XY is our plane of choice. Take the unit circle centered at the origin on that plane. Cross with $\hat{v}$. Normalize to unit magnitude. Multiply by $r$ and add $\vec{c}$.
$$r\frac{(\cos(\theta)\hat{i}+\sin(\theta)\hat{j})\times \hat{v}}{|(\cos(\theta)\hat{i}+\sin(\theta)\hat{j})\times \hat{v}|}+\vec{c}$$

.

[Please comment if any errors are found.]

Comment: This seems great! Can you show method 2 for an arbitrary plane? Cuz at the moment, that equation means the cross product will find a normal to v and the vector specified by $$r\frac{(\cos(\theta)\hat{i}+\sin(\theta)\hat{j})$$ which is some arbitrary vector in the XY plane but none of the vectors in the plane tangent to v is in that plane, so I'm a bit confused

Comment: Can you visualize the plane created by the XY plane vector and v? The cross product is normal to that plane. So, it is also perpendicular to the vector v. Can you specify which part you didn't get?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?